# Why does the following javascript code run?

Tags: javascript, json

I've borrowed the following code from a friend for getting an understanding but I'm stuck up here:-

```js
function menubar() {
  var menu = '{"str":[{"mitem":"Homepage","id":"1"},{"mitem":"About Us","id":"2"},{"mitem":"Contact Us","id":"3"},' + '{"mitem":"Feedback","id":"4"}]}'

  var jsobj = JSON.parse(menu);

  var stringbody = '';

  for (i = 0; i < jsobj.str.length; i++) {
    stringbody += '<a href="javascript:callme(' + jsobj.str[i].id + ');">' +
      '<div id="menubar">' + jsobj.str[i].mitem + '</div></a>';
  }
  document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = stringbody;
}

window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("items");
  var y = document.getElementById("iconmain");

  y.onclick = function() {
    x.style.display = (x.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="page1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="page1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="header"><h1>XYZ Gym</h1></div>
        <div id="menu"></div>
        
        <script>
            menubar();
        </script>
        
        <div id="iconmain">
            <div id="icon"></div>
            <div id="icon"></div>
            <div id="icon"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="items">
            <ul>
                <hr>
                <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li><hr>
                <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li><hr>
                <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li><hr>
                <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li><hr>
                <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li><hr>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br><br></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, the code seems to function perfectly on brackets software. But we have a function under the (href) tag - javascript:callme() which we have never defined !

Is this a predefined function? Because I don't have any other link to any other javascript file as you can see but still the code seems to run.[image]

And in case I remove that line so that I make it
 `stringbody+='<div id="menubar">'+jsobj.str[i].mitem+'</div></a>';`

Then I get the following output:-
[image]
So obviously it is not a redundant piece of code..

Comment: Don’t just delete the `<a>` entirely; you should see the same result with `<a href="http://example.com/">`.

Comment: You're removing the entire `a` tag, that's why it messes up the style. But even if the function `callme` doesn't exist it'll be displayed correctly, you'll just end up with an error when you'll click on the anchor.

Comment: ah i see now, thanks so much both of you! I've been breaking my head over this for such a long time! perhaps either of you could write an answer that i could select as the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not a predefined function, debug your code in Chrome it will show this error

```
VM196:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: callme is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM196:1
```

CSS styles gets applied to your HTML, if the selector defined in CSS is found in HTML, so the change stringbody should be like this, notice that I didn't omit the starting anchor tag

```
stringbody+= '<a href="http://www.google.com">'+
                                    '<div id="menubar">'+jsobj.str[i].mitem+'</div></a>';
```

Any link can be used in place of http://www.google.com